# How to calculate probability of something which I don't even know the distribution of?

Tags: probability

$$ \eta \sim F\left( \eta \right) $$

where eta is iid of that distribution. There is no other information about F, so we can't assume that it's a normal distribution.

then I know that

$$ Pr\left( \eta _{1} < \overline {\eta }\right) =\dfrac {1} {2}
$$

but what is

$$ Pr\left( \dfrac {\alpha } {\alpha -1}\eta _{1} < \overline {\eta }\right) $$
where 
$$ \alpha \in \left( 0,1\right) $$

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What is $\overline {\eta }$? (mean, median)? Sounds like *some* information about F.

Comment: it's the mean of eta

Comment: If all you know is the mean that's not much to go on, as many distinct distributions have the same mean, similar to saying you have polynomial P and know that $P(x_0)=1/2$ and that's it.

Comment: yeah i know, i just don't get what this is all about either

Comment: You realize that $\alpha/(\alpha-1)\lt0$, don't you? Is this intended?

Comment: Another question is how you know that $P(\eta_1\lt\bar\eta)=\frac12$. This is not true in general.

Comment: Yes for the first question. To the 2nd question, I assumed that, but yeah now I see that it may not actually be true.

Comment: Please use @ to answer comments. And, if no sensible question remains here, please delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Is $F$ supposed to be the cumulative distribution function of this same random variable $\eta$?  Then your equation $\eta \sim F(\eta)$ says that 
$$ F(t) = P(\eta \le t) = P(F(\eta) \le t)$$
But then we must have $F(\eta) = \eta$ with probability $1$.  If $\eta$ is a continuous random variable, its distribution must be uniform on $[0,1]$.